# Bounding a mth order derivative by the supremum of the function.

Tags: inequality

Suppose I had a function $k(t)$, strictly positive, real analytic. On a finite interval $(a,b)$ I see that I can bound $k'(t)$ by $k(t)$

$$\sup_{t\in(a,b)}|\frac{dk}{dt}|\leq C_{1}\sup_{t\in(a,b)}|k(t)|$$

$$C_{1}=\sup_{t\in(a,b)}\frac{\frac{dk(t)}{dt}}{k(t)}$$

Is there any reason to not assume that

$$\sup_{t\in(a,b)}|\frac{d^{m}k}{dt^{m}}|\leq C_{m}\sup_{t=\in(a,b)}|k(t)|$$

Where

$$C_{m}=\sup_{t\in(a,b)}\frac{\frac{d^{m}k(t)}{dt^{m}}}{k(t)}$$

And that each $C_{m}$ is bounded.

Comment: Important distinction: Do you mean that the entire set of constants $C_m$ is bounded, or simply that $C_m$ is always bounded for a particular $m$? (In other words, do we allow for $C_m$ to become arbitrarily large as $m$ grows?)

Comment: I've posted an answer assuming you do not allow for arbitrarily large $C_m$, as this seems to me the most likely interpretation of your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two very good reasons not to assume that:

1. You have not proved it.
2. There is a counterexample. :)

Consider the function $k(t)=\cos(2t)$ in a small region $(-\delta,\delta)$ centered around $t=0$.
$$C_1 = \sup_{t \in (-\delta,\delta)} \frac{-2\sin(2t)}{\cos(2t)} = \sup_{t \in (-\delta,\delta)} -2\tan(2t)$$
We can make this value as small as we want by shrinking $\delta$. But when $m$ is a multiple of 4, we have $\frac{d^m}{dt^m}\cos(2t)=2^m\cos(2t)$. Hence,
$$C_m = \sup_{t \in (-\delta,\delta)}\frac{2^m\cos(2t)}{\cos(2t)}=2^m$$
which is unbounded as $m$ grows.

Comment: In a larger project that I am working on, I was hoping that each element of the set was bounded. So that the limit of the sequence Cm would be convergent. But your example shows that my not well thought out hope was false. I will now be working out if the growth of Cm can be bounded by factorial growth. This should come from the definition of k(t) being real analytic.